# Prevent user to type in a textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox in MVC like this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pickup_Schedule_Date, new { @class = "dpicker", @placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy", @id = "Pickupdate",@style="cursor:pointer" })
```

User should not be able to type in the text box and it should support tab out. The above code allows tab out but also allows to type date. Suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: make it disabled with `disabled="disabled"` attribute.

Comment: If you want tab support you want `readonly` rather than `disabled` - I believe disabled makes the control un-tabbable (I think this applies in most/all browsers)

Comment: Thanks Charleh. Adding readonly also makes user to type. Can you send some piece of code.

Comment: Simple as `<input readonly>`, probably just need to add to the HTML attribs anonymous object: `new { readonly = "true" }`. Also you only need `@` for `@class` since it's a keyword, you don't need `@` symbol for `id`, `style`, `placeholder` etc

Comment: Thanks Charleh.. that works..:)